# Problem With Displaying Product Category on Product Page

Tags: wordpress

I've got a shop made with WooCommerce, every product has 2 categories

like:

An Intel CPU, should have 2 categories, Intel and CPU
the problem is, when I add those categories, WooCommerce lists them in A-Z order, not in priority order, so it shows like this:

Product Category: CPU, INTEL

the proper way I'm looking for looks like this:

Product Category: Intel, CPU

What should I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist, and what specific problem you need help with. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a temporary fix, I used A-Z Sort in a good way,
I tried and added some Unicode Glyphs that come before A in A-Z order
like □ or ◆

Answer (score 0):

you can drag and change category by "Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order" plugin. The plugin will simply list all your categories on that page, and you can manually drag and drop to rearrange category order.